# How do I read this function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, jquery-selectors

```
function showTweet(username) {
    $( "<ul/>", {
        "class": "my-user-list",
        html: usertweets[username].join( "<li/>" )
    }).appendTo( $("#tweets") );
}
```

So I see that the selector is targeting an unordered list, but what comes after the comma and why is it in curly brackets?

I understand the `.append` portion. I do not understand what `"class": "my-user-list"` and `html: usertweets[username].join( "<li/>")` do. Note that `usertweets` is an array.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: All in the documentation: [Jquery Create Element w/ attributes](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-html-attributes)

Comment: it's jquery...http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1

Comment: It's checking the `usertweets` object for the `username` key and wrapping the resulting value in `li` tags (which is placed in the `ul`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The selector is not targeting a `ul` - it is creating one. The second parameter is an object that contains the properties to set on the new `ul` element. It is then added to the DOM by appending it to the `#tweets` element.

To show the difference:

```
// to create a ul element in memory
$('<ul></ul>'); // or...
$('<ul />');  

// select all ul elements currently in the DOM
$('ul');
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not targeting ul, it first creates a `<ul>` element, and set the `<ul>`'s  `class` to `"my-user-list"`, then set its the html inside it to `usertweets[username].join("<li/>")`, which should creates some `<li>`, and finally append the newly created `<ul>` and the `<li>`s inside it to `$("#tweets")`.

You can see more from [jQuery#.jQuery()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-html-attributes).

Answer (score 2):

The curly brackets are for [PlainObject](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#PlainObject) which is plain JavaScript object. From that I would read

Please create me a `<ul>` with class `my-user-list` with html of lists of usertweets joined with `<li/>` and append that to `<ul>` and append the ul to an element with id `tweets`

Here's the example

http://jsfiddle.net/xz6a0yqy/